# How to load n-th to m-th rows using SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to load nth to nth records using a SQL query?

Something like

```
select 10 to 20 columnname from tbl order by columnname
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2012 has a new feature called `OFFSET` and `FETCH`:

```
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY columnName
  OFFSET 10 ROWS 
  FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2012-sql-order-by-offset-fetch-next-rows.aspx

In versions prior to 2012, the best approach is to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) with a `ROW_NUMBER()` function and select from that CTE using the row numbers - [see more details here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/11/sql-server-2005-t-sql-paging-query-technique-comparison-over-and-row_number-cte-vs-derived-table/)

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. Simplifies my code so much when I found this.

Comment: @user475464: the CTE/ROW_NUMBER() approach works for 2005 and newer

Answer (score 0):

For SQL 2005 and above you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
 DECLARE @p0 Int = 10
 DECLARE @p1 Int = 10

 SELECT [t1].[pkCompanyID]
 FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[pkCompanyID]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[pkCompanyID]
     FROM [tblCompany] AS [t0]
     ) AS [t1]
 WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
 ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
```